# Should "Closing this question because I didn't get an answer" posts be flagged as "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

While reviewing the 10k queue just now, I noticed that someone has evidently searched for and flagged self-accepted answers like

- [Closing this question as we would probably get no further.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858600/1127114)
- [Closing out this question as no one else has responded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6082826/1127114)
- [Closing out this question...no responses in a few months.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422332/1127114)

What is the proper way to handle [answers like these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%22closing+this+question%22)? Should they be flagged as "not an answer", or should they be left alone?

On the one hand, these answers obviously make no attempt to answer the question. On the other hand, these answers may imply that "I'm no longer looking for an answer — don't bug me."

Comment: They make no attempt to answer the question, and we're about building a repository of knowledge - in my humble opinion, flag them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They still aren't answers, since they don't make any attempt at answering the original question.

They *should* be flagged as such.